# How to force Docker to use an internal address without accepting connections from outside?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have an internal address (eth0), I need the docker to work only with it, how can I implement this?

> inet addr:10.0.0.19  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

My Docker-compose

```
 ports:
  - "4200:4200"
command: npm run start -- --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you really want to do?

Comment: @aiqency I need to have access to the container only inside the server

Comment: And you have other containers in the same server that has to talk to it. Correct?